# How to use react select2 wrapper with browserify?

Tags: browserify

I'm trying to use this https://github.com/rkit/react-select2-wrapper in my browserify'd js.. like this:

```
var React = require("react");
import Select2 from 'react-select2-wrapper';

    <Select2 options={{
                placeholder: 'Select Location'
              }}/>
```

But I get an error when compiling: `Browserify Failed!: Cannot find module 'jquery.mousewheel'`

I'm probably doing something wrong. Any ideas please?

Comment: Did you get this working? I've hit the same issue.

Comment: @Bowen - Hey, no I havn't found a solution yet. There is a bug listed here https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3287

Comment: Try doing a "npm install jquery.mousewheel" I've actually ended up writing my "version" of this module, I'll try and get it in a gist for you today

Comment: hey @Bowen, did you get it working?

Comment: So I went with https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select instead.. it's decent

Comment: The above github issue was closed in November. I try to use a very similar `https://github.com/luqin/react-select2/`, and if you look at it's `packages.json`, it contains a `jquery` dependency besides `select2` and `shallow-equal-fuzzy`. Looking at the install the `select2` dependency pulls in `almond` and `jquery-mousewheel`. I use a build pipeline with browserify and don't have an error.

Comment: Looks like I gonna go with `react-select` too for AJAX data source